# custom post type single page not found after aotumatic publish By the author's robot

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, post-type

I use a plugin that has a custom post type and when I publish a post it is displayed on a single page but when the post is automatically published using a author's robot plugin, unfortunately the single page is not found and shows error 404!!
My custom post type in the class is as follows:

```
<?php
/*------------------------
function init
-------------------------*/
    static function init(){
        add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'register_post_types' ) );
    }
/*------------------------
register post type
-------------------------*/
 static function register_post_types(){
    $labels = array(
         //custom post type
    );
    $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'public'            => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'hierarchical'      => false,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'jobtest'),
            'query_var'         => true,
            'has_archive'       => true,
            'supports'          => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'iwj_job' , $args );
}
```

I have the main plugin file with this function:

```
public function init_hooks() {
     register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'IWJ_active', 'activate' ) );
}
```

Then within my class I have this:

```
   static function activate() {
     IWJ_Post_Types::register_post_types();
     flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
```

I don't know why when I use the Author Robot Plugin for publish a post, custom post type single page not found?? but it works when I manually update it again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with my reviews. I put the following code into a query.class.php file and the problem was resolved.

```
static function init(){
    if (!is_blog_admin()) {
        add_action('parse_query', array(__CLASS__, 'parse_query'));
    }
}

static function parse_query($query) {
    if(!is_blog_admin() && ($query->get('post_type') == 'iwj_job' || is_tax(iwj_get_job_taxonomies())) && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'iwj_job' ) );
    }           
}
```